# Jetty Consumes 100% CPU, it's like a Jetty BUG

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, profiling, cpu-usage

There is a Java web-app that is running by `Jetty 9.4.1.v20170120`

**UPDATE:**
*The same result by `Jetty 9.4.3.v20170317`*

---

this web-app has a `TCP-client` and using `Web-socket` (`Atmosphere`) to push data.

After some minutes/hours of working, the web-app starts to use 100% CPU *without any specific reason*. Even when it is `idle`.

After profiling and getting thread-dumps, it seems that `Jetty` is the source of high CPU consumption.

**So what is wrong with Jetty? is this a bug?**

Below I list some evidences after profiling (using `VisualVM`) when CPU consumption reach to 100%:

- Running threads ***(CLICK to enlarge images)***:
  [image: Running threads with highest running time]
- CPU Sampler:
  [image: Highest called commands]
- CPU Sampler-per thread:
  [image: Per-thread cpu times]
- Memory Sampler:
  [image: Per-thread memory size]
- Process status (using processExplorer):
  [image: status of the process]
- Process performance (using processExplorer):
  [image: Process performance]

Comment: I don't know if you can [*sample it under a debugger*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), but if you can, infinite loops are the easiest thing in the world to find. Once it's hung, every stack sample is certain to be in the problem. 1, 2, or 3 samples should be all you need. The culprit is on every stack sample.